# Jenkins Cobertura Plugin - reset Ratcheting / autoUpdateHealth values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cobertura

We're using the Jenkins Cobertura Plugin and it has been working great so far. We use the following configuration

```
  cobertura coberturaReportFile: 'build/coverage.xml',
    autoUpdateHealth: true,
    enableNewApi: true,
    failUnhealthy: true,
    failUnstable: false,
    maxNumberOfBuilds: 0,
    lineCoverageTargets: "70, 20, 25",
    onlyStable: false
```

This automatically tightens the health requirements from build to build. However, we have had an intentional regression in coverage and now builds are failing because of the tightened targets.

I would like to reset the stored target values, so the next build uses the configured values again. How do I do that?

Comment: I figured that building with `autoUpdateHealth: false` and `autoUpdateStability: false` will at least ignore the ratcheted values. Not sure if it will reset them.

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same issue. FWIW, I have confirmed that if we update our build and set the properties:

```
autoUpdateHealth: false, autoUpdateStability: false
```

Run the build on master and then update them back to

```
autoUpdateHealth: true, autoUpdateStability: true
```

that appears to reset the internal mechanism.

Obviously, this is less than desirable as it forces us to add two pointless changes to our master branch for something that should be handled in Jenkins.

I see that you also [filed an issue with the Cobetura plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cobertura-plugin/issues/124), just linking it here for convenience.